# Property 'count' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript

How do I get rid of Typescript errors for the data structure passed into a `then` promise?

I am getting the following error:

> Property 'count' does not exist on type '{}'

For the following code:

```js
this.userData.getSocialLinks(this.navParams.get('image_owner_id')).then(socialLinks => {
  var i = 0;
  for (i=0; i < socialLinks.count; i++) {
    if (socialLinks.results[i].social_type == 'TW') {
      this.profile.twitter = socialLinks.results[i].social_address;
      this.isExistingTW = true;
      this.twEntryID = socialLinks.results[i].id;
    }
    else if (socialLinks.results[i].social_type == 'IN') {
      this.profile.instagram = socialLinks.results[i].social_address;
      this.isExistingIN = true;
      this.inEntryID = socialLinks.results[i].id;
    }
  }
});
```

I am guessing I have to define `socialLinks` somehow but can't work out where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way, is to create some kind of interface and use it as a type:

```
// describe what is coming    
export interface IData<T> {
    count: number;    
    results: T[];
}

// use that IData
this.userData
 .getSocialLinks(this.navParams.get('image_owner_id'))
 .then(( socialLinks: IData<any>) => {
```

In case, there is more clear what T is, e.g. `IPerson`... we can use `IData<IPerson>`

Play with [that here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20IData%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20results%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.userData.getSocialLinks(this.navParams.get('image_owner_id'))%0D%0A%09%20.then((%20socialLinks%3A%20IData%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(i%3D0%3B%20i%20%3C%20socialLinks.count%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.social_type%20%3D%3D%20'TW')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.profile.twitter%20%3D%20socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.social_address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.isExistingTW%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.twEntryID%20%3D%20socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.id%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.social_type%20%3D%3D%20'IN')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.profile.instagram%20%3D%20socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.social_address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.isExistingIN%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inEntryID%20%3D%20socialLinks.results%5Bi%5D.id%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B)